# Get and print directories from $PATH in bash

Tags: linux, bash, path-variables

The script that I have to write must find the directories from the `$PATH` variable and print only the ones that end with an i.

**How am I thinking about doing it**

- Get each directory from the variable with a for loop.
- Find the length of each directory and get the last character from each using a substring
- Use an If condition to print the directories that end with an i

**Problems**

- The directories are not separated with a new line and I can't read them using a for loop.

Any ideas on how to get over this problem,or can you think of something more appropriate.

Comment: This was my only idea.My knowledge in this area is pretty poor I should say.

Comment: Note that the `==` operator in bash's `[[ ... ]]` is a *pattern matching* operator, and a pattern to find a word that begins with "x" is `x*`

Comment: spend some time reading about bash "word splitting". One resource is http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting. There are innumerable examples here on stackoverflow.

Comment: So basicaly you are saying that I don't need to find the substring of the string,but instead use string == *i ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this BASH one-liner for that job:

```
(IFS=':'; for i in $PATH; do [[ -d "$i" && $i =~ i$ ]] && echo "$i"; done)
```

- `IFS=':'` sets input field separator to `:`
- `$PATH` is iterated in a `for loop`
- Each path element is tested if it is a directory and if it is ending with `i` using BASH regex
- If test passes then it is pritned

Comment: in for loop I was thinking `if [ ${str:${#str} - $1} = i ]`

Answer (score 1):

Use bash's [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) to replace all delimiters.

```
${parameter//pat/string}
```

For example,

```
mypaths="${PATH//:/ }"
```

will split the path by directory, so then you can run:

```
for directory in $mypaths
do
    ...
done
```

Comment: +1 for showing me how to use the for loop correctly by using this code.

Answer (score 0):

Note:

- The question includes a *very specific, incidental* requirement: to find `PATH` entries *ending in `i`*, which the answer in the next section accommodates.
- If your intent is to **simply print *all* `PATH` entries, *each on its own line***:

  ```bash
  printf '%s\n' "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"
  ```

---

**Answer to the question *as asked*:**

```bash
grep 'i$' <<<"${PATH//:/$'\n'}"
```

- The `$PATH` entries are split into individual lines by replacing `:` instances with newlines (`$'\n'`) in a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe); `$'\n'` is an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).
- The resulting strings is passed to the stdin of `grep` as a [here-string](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument?action=show&redirect=HereString)
  (`<<<...`).
- `grep` is then used to match only those lines that end in (`$`) the letter `i`.
  To match case-insensitively, use `grep -i 'i$'`.

A demonstration:

```bash
$ (PATH='/ends/in_i:/usr/bin:/also/ends_in_i'; grep 'i$' <<<"${PATH//:/$'\n'}")
/ends/in_i
/also/ends_in_i
```

Note how `/usr/bin` is - as intended - not included in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the *Inter Field Separator* (IFS) to colon then path is dissected auto_magically. ;-)

```
IFS=:
for i in $PATH
do
 echo $i | egrep -e 'i$'
done
```